# Fix buttons at the bottom of Material-UI dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have to fix buttons on the bottom of my Material-UI dialog. I mean buttons should be in the bottom of dialog all the time regardless dialog size, list size, etc.
so far I have tried position: "fixed", bottom: 0, they are not helpful. 
Any suggestions?

I am using MaterialUI Grid (its not a table in the screen).

[image]

Comment: Put the button's in `<DialogActions>` tag.

Comment: Please paste what you have tried so far and didn't work, we cannot help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, It was fixed by using MaterialGrid and adding some styles (display: "flex", height: "80px", justifyContent: "space-between")

Answer (score 2):

**Mixing Material UI Dialog Components with HTML elements can short circuit proper flow of Material UI component**.

What I had... footer buttons failed to fix to the bottom... notice the body message is in a HTML div and the footer is in a material UI DialogActions

```
<Dialog>
  <div>body message</div>
  
  <DialogActions>
    <Button>Cancel</Button> <Button>Save</Button>
  </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

I fixed it by inserting the body-message div into the Material UI DialogContent component... this made the DialogActions do what it was supposed to do (stay fixed at the bottom).

```
<Dialog>
  <DialogContent>
      <div>body message</div>
  </DialogContent>
  
  <DialogActions>
    <Button>Cancel</Button> <Button>Save</Button>
  </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it looks like you're displaying a Table in a Dialog.
From this conclusion it is suggested -

> 1. To embed your 'Table' component inside 'DialogContent'
> 2. The button should be right aligned on the Dialog, meaning your buttons
>    should be placed inside 'DialogActions'

I created a sandbox with some mock data (due to insufficient details in the question) - Have a look - https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-dialog-actions-qcrnx

Comment: As I already mentioned above its not a table, it is MaterialUI Grid. who is using tables today :) ?